# Count For Points Within Coordinates for a circle, rectangle and triangle c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program to count the number of points within a circle, triangle and 4 sided polygon. I have about 3500 coordinates, and i want to be able to find out the count for the number of coordinates within these shapes, e.g. for the circle i want to put the centre coordinates and the radius and find the count. Or for the an square like shape, i currently have a formula to take 4 points, and using bubble sort so that way i can order the way that the area is calculated from the points, but i think I'm going around this the wrong way, i have only just started on this code and will put it up but please bare with as I'm just trying to get my head round it before filling it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void bubblesort(vector<double>& vec) 
{
double s = vec.size();
for (int i=0; i<s; i++) 
    {
    for (int j=i+1; j<s; j++) 
        {
        if (vec[i] < vec[j]) 
            {
            double x = vec[i];
            vec[i] = vec[j];
            vec[j] = x;
            }
        }
    }
}

void squarecount(vector<double>& a, vector<double>& b)
{
    // I am thinking here to put the x,y coordinates, linking each two and getting 4 equations counting the number satisfying all 4 inequalities
}

int main ()
{
    double a;
    cout << "Please enter the corresponding numberthe shape for which you want to find the count of in your data;" << endl;
    cout << "Circle (1)" << endl;
    cout << "Triangle (2) " << endl;
    cout << "4 Sided Polygon (3)" << endl;
    cin >> a;

    if ( a == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (a == 2)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (a == 3)
    {
        vector<double> data1;
        vector<double> data2;
        // 4 Sided Polygon
        double x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4;
        cout << "Enter the first x coordinate then press enter, then the corresponding y coordinate" << endl;
        cin >> data1[0];
        cin >> data2[0];
        cout << "Enter the second x coordinate then press enter, then the corresponding y coordinate" << endl;
        cin >> data1[1];
        cin >> data2[1];
        cout << "Enter the second x coordinate then press enter, then the corresponding y coordinate" << endl;
        cin >> data1[2];
        cin >> data2[2];
        cout << "Enter the second x coordinate then press enter, then the corresponding y coordinate" << endl;
        cin >> data1[3];
        cin >> data2[3];
        bubblesort(data1);
        bubblesort(data2);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid Input!" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter either 1 for a circle, 2 for a triangle or 3 for a a 4 sided pollygon" << endl;

    }


 }
```

Comment: I guess we should assume that the circle is pixelated. Otherwise what do mean by a point.

Comment: What's the question? You only need one point and a dimension to find a square. Also, why not use something like `std::sort`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you want to write into a `vector` you should use `push_back(.)` or `resize` the vector first. I am not sure what you want to use the sorting algorithm for.

Also, there is no need to reinvent the wheel. There are existing algorithms to check, if a point is inside a polygon (or a circle). All you need to do is to test this for all your points and count the number of points inside the shape.
The circle is trivial: just check if the distance from your point to the center is smaller than the radius.
The polygon is a little more complicated: [point in polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon). The [ray-casting, even-odd rule algorithm](https://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html) could be implemented like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

bool checkPoly(double x, double y, vector<double> xCorners, vector<double> yCorners){

    int num=xCorners.size();
    int j=num-1;
    bool res=false;

    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
        if((yCorners[i]>y) != (yCorners[j]>y) && (x<(xCorners[j]-xCorners[i])*(y-yCorners[i])/(yCorners[j]-yCorners[i])+xCorners[i])){
            res = !res;
        }
        j=i;
    }
    return res;
}

bool checkCircle(double x, double y, double xCenter, double yCenter, double radius){
    if(sqrt(pow(x-xCenter,2)+pow(y-yCenter,2)) < radius){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(){
    //POLYGON
    vector<double> xCorners;
    vector<double> yCorners;
    xCorners.push_back(3);
    yCorners.push_back(2);

    xCorners.push_back(5);
    yCorners.push_back(6);

    xCorners.push_back(8);
    yCorners.push_back(4);
    bool resPoly=false;

    //CIRCLE
    double xCenter=5;
    double yCenter=4;
    double radius=2.5;
    bool resCircle=false;

    for(int x=0;x<10;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<10;y++){
            resPoly=checkPoly(x,y,xCorners,yCorners);
            resCircle=checkCircle(x,y,xCenter,yCenter,radius);
            if(resPoly){
                cout<<"("<<x<<", "<<y<<") is inside the polygon."<<endl;
            }else{
                cout<<"("<<x<<", "<<y<<") is outside the polygon."<<endl;
            }
            if(resCircle){
                cout<<"("<<x<<", "<<y<<") is inside the circle."<<endl;
            }else{
                cout<<"("<<x<<", "<<y<<") is outside the circle."<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here, it is checked if all the points with x=0,...,10 and y=0,...,10 are inside

1. a triangle with corners (3,2),(5,6) and (8,4)
2. a circle with radius 2.5 and center (5,4)

Note that the ray casting algorithm is also valid for higher number of corners (for higher number of corners the order of the corners define the polygon).